# Inverse of a log function.

Tags: calculus, functions

I need to find the inverse of:

$$f(x) = -x-\ln(1-x),\quad x\in[0,1). $$

I can find it using matlab but I need to find it also for $x\in(-5,0)$ but I could not do by matlab!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a solution in terms of [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

> $$ x = W(-e^{-y-1})+ 1. $$

Comment: Thanks. Does it work for both ranges?

Comment: @Ahmad: This how to find the inverse! However to prove a function has inverse then the function should satisfy some conditions.

Comment: @Ahmad: Your function is decreasing on the interval $(-.5,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

As @science has stated, you can use the [Lambert $W$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function to find the inverse of your equation. However, for your range of $x$, the inverse will be defined in terms of two [branches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point) of this multi-valued function. For $x \in [0,\infty)$, the solution is in terms of the upper branch, denoted $W_0(x)$, and for $x \in (-\infty,0]$, it is in terms of the lower branch, denoted $W_{-1}(x)$. In Matlab, you can use the `lambertw` function [(documentation)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/lambertw.html) to evaluate this, making sure that you call the two-argumnent form to specify the branch. So, for your $x \in (-5,0)$, you can use

```
x = lambertw(-1,-exp(-y-1))+1
```

while for $x \in [0,1)$, you can use

```
x = lambertw(0,-exp(-y-1))+1
```

Yes, you need to have an idea of the output, $x$, in order to decide which solution to choose.

For $x$ outside of the $(0, 1]$ part of your domain, the inverse of your function can also be written in terms of the [Wright $\omega$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Omega_function) function with complex arguments, which is related to the [Lambert $W$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function:

$$x = \omega(- y - 1 -\pi \mathbb{i}) + 1$$

In Matlab you can solve for the inverse of your function using the Symbolic Math toolbox:

```
syms x y
x = solve(y == -x-log(1-x),x)
```

which, in R2014b, returns:

```
x =

wrightOmega(- pi*1i - y - 1) + 1
```

This uses the Matlab's symbolic `wrightOmega` function ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/wrightomega.html)). This function works with double precision inputs, but it can be slow and had numerical bugs, specifically for the situation where the imaginary part of the input is exactly $\pm \pi \text{i}$, as in your case (perhaps this is the source of your problem?). So care must be taken to ensure `wrightOmega` evaluates symbolically:

```
x = double(wrightOmega(sym(-y-1)-sym('pi')*1i))+1
```

This converts your input $y$ to a symbolic value and also ensures that $\pi$ is represented exactly before passing everything into `wrightOmega`. The output is converted back to a double-precison floating-point value.

A much faster option that avoids symbolic math, is to use `wrightOmegaq` ([Matlab code](https://github.com/horchler/SHCTools/blob/master/SHCTools/stoneholmes/private/wrightOmegaq.m)), my fully-vectorized and documented implementation of the algorithm in the paper: *[Complex Double-Precision Evaluation of the Wright omega Function](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2168773.2168779)* by Lawrence, et al.